# How did I get Healing Done as D.Va?

Tags: overwatch

I played some Total Mayhem. This was my end card:

[image: End card as D.Va with 13 healing done]

...how did D.Va get any healing done at all? Is it her ultimate?

The game made me [this highlight from the match](https://gfycat.com/TautSilentLeopard). You can see the health go up by 13 exactly at the very end, though this might be entirely a coincidence.

Comment: That health gain in the highlight is for sitting on the cart, but it shouldn't count towards the healing done medal, just like health packs don't count most of the time.

Comment: Please note that [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com) will shut down on Sept. 1, 2023. This affects the media you included in your post since they were uploaded to Gfycat. I recommend that you edit your post and reupload the media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You might need to edit the media to make it ≤ 2 MiB, which is the maximum file size allowed by SE Imgur. See [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16826/4797) for more info.

Answer (score 15):

It appears that when D.Va deletes a Moira's Biotic Orb with Defense Matrix, she gains ownership of it for a split moment. Any healing that the orb is doing at the time of it being deleted is credited to D.Va.

A similar, but rarer bug has been around for a long time and is known to affect Junkrat as well. I am not sure about the causes of that one, but it seems related to getting healed while calling a new MEKA.

Comment: With the bug referring to her getting back into the MEKA, I believe that that is due to her being restored back to 150hp before actually getting into the MEKA.

Comment: This would also explain the friendly fire team kills D.Va occasionally gets with negative Biotic Orb.